How to Convert 2D Lines from a DXF File into 3D Walls in Unity?
I'm working on a Unity project where I need to automatically generate 3D walls based on 2D lines extracted from a .dxf floorplan (AutoCAD format). I'm using the IxMilia.Dxf library to read the DXF file and extract 2D geometric data, specifically LINE entities, but I'm unsure how to transform this 2D data into vertical 3D planes to represent walls.
What I've Done:

Reading DXF Files: I'm using IxMilia.Dxf to read DXF files and extract relevant entities like LINE.

Extracting 2D Line Data: I'm able to successfully get the coordinates for each line in the 2D space.


My Goal:
I want to convert these 2D lines into 3D vertical planes in Unity to represent walls.
Example Code:
Here’s the code I’m using to extract the 2D lines from the DXF file:
using IxMilia.Dxf;
using IxMilia.Dxf.Entities;
using UnityEngine;

public class DxfReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string dxfFilePath;

    void Start()
    {
        DxfFile dxfFile = DxfFile.Load(dxfFilePath);

        foreach (var entity in dxfFile.Entities)
        {
            if (entity is DxfLine line)
            {
                Vector3 start = new Vector3((float)line.P1.X, 0, (float)line.P1.Y);
                Vector3 end = new Vector3((float)line.P2.X, 0, (float)line.P2.Y);

                Debug.Log($"Line from {start} to {end}");
                // How can I convert this line into a 3D wall?
            }
        }
    }
}

Question:
How can I convert the extracted 2D LINE entities into vertical 3D planes (walls) in Unity? Any guidance on generating simple 3D geometry based on these 2D coordinates would be helpful.
